# When assigning a char array to union datatype, my compiler throws an error: "conversion from char* to non-scalar type"

Tags: c, unions, type-conversion

Let me explain the overall function of my program. A user can enter a string, and that string is hashed according to the MD5 Hash algorithm.  It then prints the string to stdout.

I found that using a union structure simplified the code:

```
union md5hash
{
     uint ui[4]; //= 16 bytes --> 128 bits 
     char ch[16]; //= 16 bytes --> 128 bits
};
```

My program works fine in that situation.

However, I would like to expand the functionality of my program. Instead of entering a string to be hashed, I would like an MD5 hash to be entered via stdin.

Here's a short program that attempts to replicate this functionality:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

typedef unsigned int uint;

union md5hash
{
    uint ui[4]; //= 16 bytes --> 128 bits 
    char ch[16]; //= 16 bytes --> 128 bits
};

int main(void){


    std::string hash = "abcdefghjklqwertyuiopasdfghjklzx";
    std::cout << hash.length();
    char* chash = (char*) malloc(sizeof(hash.length()+1));
    memcpy(chash, hash.c_str(), hash.size()+1);
    for(int i = 0; chash[i] ; i++) printf("%c",chash[i]);
    md5hash test =  chash;
    getchar();

}
```

Yes, I know my array is 32 characters long, and the array in the union is only 16 characters (that's a problem I have yet to address). In any case, I need the hash entered via stdin to be in the same form as a string that is hashed.

For example:

```
Enter string: "Hello"
Goes through hash algorithm: 5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592

Enter hash:"5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592"

Are they equal? (Compare their hash values).
```

However, hash is a char array, while the hashed value is an md5hash datatype. How can I convert the hash entered through stdin to an md5hash datatype?

Also, I am using Dev C++ - which uses the Mingw port of GCC (GNU Compiler Collection) as it's compiler. The error I receive is

```
 conversion from `char*' to non-scalar type `md5hash' requested.
```

(I'm not surprised that I received an error from the above program).

Any constructive input is appreciated.

EDIT:

This is how I am hashing my strings (it's not the full code, but this is how a string is prepared for hashing):

```
void md5_prep(char *c0)
{
  uint len = 0;
  char *c = c0; 
  while(*c) {len++; c++;}
  c[0] = 0x80; // bit 1 after the message (Appears counterintuitive, but remember c was incremented in the above loop
  ((uint*)c0)[14] = len * 8;    // message length in bits (Note: 4 * 14 is 56 - appends to end of buffer as stated in Wikipedia's psuedocode)
}

void print_md5(uint *hash, bool crlf)
{
  for(int i = 0; i != 16; i++) { printf("%02x", (uint)(((unsigned char *)hash)[i])); }
  if(crlf) printf("\n");
}

union md5hash
{
  uint ui[4]; //= 16 bytes --> 128 bits (allows the message to be divided into chunks due to union structure)
  char ch[16]; //= 16 bytes --> 128 bits
};


md5hash single_md5(char* ptext)
{
  md5hash h;

  char w[64] = {0}; //Declare an empty array
  //for(int i = 0; ptext[i]; i++) w[i] = ptext[i];
  strncpy(w, ptext, 56); //Copy over the text to be hashed; this effectively "zero pads" the string (limiting to 56 - my choice)
  md5_prep(w);
  MD5_CPU((uint*)&w[0], h.ui[0], h.ui[1], h.ui[2], h.ui[3]); //Hash the message

  return h;
}

//Test
int main(void){
  //Declarations
  std::string target = "Hello";

  char tes[120] = {0};
  tes[0] = 'h';
  tes[1] = 'e';
  for(int i =0; tes[i]; i++)
          printf("%c", tes[i]);
  printf("\n");

  //Execute
  md5hash test = single_md5(tes);
  print_md5(test.ui, false);

  return 0;
}
```

So, if I want to compare an entered hash to a computed hash from an entered string, I can do this

```
   a == target[0] && b == target[1] && c == target[2] && d == target[3]
```

Where `a,b,c,d` are `ui[1], ui[2], ui[3], ui[4]`.

However, I need to somehow convert the hash string into that form defined by the union.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know C had `std::string`. Cool!

Comment: (But if this, by accident, happens to be C++, then ***please please please*** don't tag it with `c`, and even more importantly, do not use `malloc()`!)

Comment: Ha, my main program is in C++, didn't realize I copied it over. Pretend that those lines don't exist. (It's supposed to be purely c).

Comment: Anyway, the problem is that you are trying to assign a pointer to a union. What do you want to achieve? It doesn't make sense (well, more precisely, *I* can't make sense of it.)

Comment: @H2CO3 It is somewhat ambiguous: the problem is that I have strings that are hashed by my program. They are of type `md5hash` in the end. I want to enter an already hashed string via stdin. In order to compare them, I need the entered hash string to be of type `md5hash` as defined by the union. So, how can I convert the string into the type `md5hash`. Let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: not sure I get it. "I need the entered hash string to be of type md5hash" - you can't store any string in that union, since its length is limited. Even in your example, `"abcdefghjklqwertyuiopasdfghjklzx"` doesn't fit into those 16 bytes.

Comment: Ok, let me add more detail to my question then - I'll do an edit to it.

Comment: @H2CO3 Considering your comment, that is partly the problem. MD5 hashes are 32 characters long (to be precise, 32 chars as hexdecimal representation). But the user is going to enter 32 characters.

Comment: If no one is working on this, I am going to delete the question and rephrase it in, I hope, a clearer way.

Comment: So... you just want to convert the textual hex representation of the hash to its 16-byte raw (not human-readable) form, right?

Comment: Yes. One that can be compared as I have stated it in my edit.

Comment: Then you can just go through the string word by word, converting each word to a byte (something like `hex2int(word[0]) << 8 | hex2int(word[1])` should do the job, where the hex2int function should create an integer given a hexadecimal character). Then *copy* the converted array onto the union: `memcpy(hash, converted, 16);`

Comment: I will look into that. Essentially, `hex2int(word[0]) through hex2int(word[31])`?

Comment: @H2CO3 If you wish to post your solution as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your problem is that the user enters a 32-bit textual (hexadecimal) representation of the hash, whereas you need the raw data. So, you will have to convert between the two:

```
int hex2int(char ch)
{
    if (isdigit(ch))
        return ch - '0';

    switch (ch) {
    case 'a': case 'A': return 10;
    case 'b': case 'B': return 11;
    case 'c': case 'C': return 12;
    case 'd': case 'D': return 13;
    case 'e': case 'E': return 14;
    case 'f': case 'F': return 15;
    default: abort(); // shan't happen
    }
}

char md5_hex2raw(char raw[16], const char hex[32])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i += 2) {
        raw[i] = (hex2int(hex[0]) << 4) | hex2int(hex[1]);
    }
}
```

You can then just call the conversion function so that it copies directly into a union:

```
md5hash hash;
md5_hex2raw(hash.ch, user_entered_string);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write a function to implement this covertion,like this:

```
 union md5hash str2md5hash(const char *str)
 {
    union md5hash out = {0};
    strcpy(out.ch,str);
    return out;
 }

 union md5hash int2md5hash(int data)
 {
    union md5hash out = {0};
    out.ui = data;
    return out;
 }
```

Comment: Interesting, does this account for the string being 32 characters whereas `ch` is 16 characters though?

Comment: @Mlagma No, it doesn't.